# Doctrine Entities Generator

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Good Day,

I'm having few issues with Doctrine entities generator while creating new project in Symfony 2 framework.

For testing purposes, I have following table called users:
id INT PK

```
username VARCHAR(80)
password VARCHAR(150)
salt VARCHAR(100)
email VARCHAR(100)
```

I created new project with no problem. I called my new bundle MyTestBundle.

After completing database design, I use `php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert yml ./src/My/TestBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force` to map database schema to Yaml format files. Then I use `php app/console doctrine:mapping:import MyTestBundle annotation` and `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MyTestBundle` to import mapping and generate entities.

I have few important questions regarding entities generation:

1. Why does it creates entity called Users instead of User? When I try to modify yml files located in `./src/My/TestBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm` the generator seems to ignore them. Any tips?
2. I need to implement my custom role provider. That's why I created two additional tables for roles storage (simplified schema below):
   `roles: id INT PK, name VARCHAR(50)`
   `users_roles: id INT PK, user_id INT, role_id INT`
   Why generator is ignoring this relation? It creates correct relations in UsersRoles class, but not in Roles or Users entities. Am I missing something?

Any help/explanation will be very appreciated.

**Edit**
I have noticed really weird thing:
I created simple Yaml schema and put it in `./src/MyTestBundle/resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm`, I called this file `User.orm.yml`. Now, when I try to import mapping or generate entities I get following error `Bundle "MyTestBundle" does not contain any mapped entities.`

Warmest greetings,
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was replied on Symfony 2 Group: http://groups.google.com/group/symfony2/browse_thread/thread/fa088382e6546679/50ab1902a573feb6?lnk=gst&q=entity+generation#50ab1902a573feb6